# Automatically logout after refreshing the page in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am Automatically logout after refreshing the page in laravel 6. Everything is working fine but I am successfully logged in but when I refresh the page automatically logged out. I am using a socialite package to login to my app. I also increase the session lifetime to 180 in config/session.php file but still didn't work...

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Models\Constant_model;
    use App\SocialProvider;
    use App\User;
    use Socialite;


   class LoginController extends Controller
   {
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


// public function __construct()
// {
//     $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
// }

public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}


public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{


    $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    $authuser = $this->findOrCreateUser($social_user,$provider);
    Auth::login($authuser,true);
    return redirect('/');


}


public function findOrCreateUser($social_user,$provider){

    $authuser = SocialProvider::where('provider_id', $social_user->id)->first();


    if(!$authuser){

      $user = User::firstOrCreate(

          ['email'=> $social_user->getEmail()],
          ['ip_address'=> '127.0.0.1'],
          ['user_name'=> $social_user->getName()],
          ['name'=> $social_user->getName()],
          ['picture'=> $social_user->getAvatar()],
          ['password'=> 'sfdsfsdffsfsfs'],


      );


      $user->socialProviders()->create(

        ['provider_id'=>$social_user->getId(), 'provider'=>$provider]

      );


      return $user;



    }else{


      $user_id = $authuser->user_id;

      $userdata = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users',"id",$user_id);

      $user = User::firstOrCreate(

        ['email'=> $userdata[0]->email],
        ['ip_address'=> '127.0.0.1'],
        ['user_name'=> $userdata[0]->username],
        ['name'=> $userdata[0]->name],
        ['picture'=> $userdata[0]->picture],
        ['password'=> 'sfdsfsdffsfsfs'],


    );


      return $user;

    }
}}
```

Comment: Is this happening on a particular page or anywhere? Could be a form re-submission. Please show your blade and routes. Could be your middleware too.

Comment: it's on page refresh(Anywhere) no its for both form submission and when i am logging using socialite...

Comment: Please dump your middleware and routes here. Also check if session is there in your browser's session storage before and after the refresh.

Comment: @QumberRizvi how please suggest